# Background image for full screen in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to set the full screen image in storyboard. It should not stretch as Apple has provided many variations in width & height. So I am using device from *iPhone SE to iPhone XS Max*. So what should be the **1x, 2X & 3X** for adding images in assets.

I tried to add `launchimage` for full screen, but that is not displaying on storyboard & neither in app.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use iPhone X resolution image and set the property as `aspectFill`. It will cut slightly but will look good.

Answer (score 0):

1. Give autoresizing constraint to your imageview.

[image]

2. Set ContentMode : Aspect Fit. Your image will not stretch

[image]

This will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But, as per you suggestion, there should be exact screen size of image, otherwise it will be display background colour on top and bottom. And for all screen there aren't possible to add all image with 1x, 2x, 3x.

Comment: And I'm using autolayout instead of auroresizing.

Comment: share your splash image with me.I will do it.